# storage_exhausted error when sending to unrevealed account

Tags: rpc, transactions

I'm trying to run an undelegation+transaction of all my XTZ to an unrevealed account on Delphinet (7.5). This also happens in Carthagenet so I'm guessing is a calculation error on my part:

The first thing I do is dry-run the operation. The `run_operation` simulation gives me:

```
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "kind": "delegation",
            "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
            "fee": "0",
            "counter": "780743",
            "gas_limit": "800000",
            "storage_limit": "60000",
            "metadata": {
                "balance_updates": [

                ],
                "operation_result": {
                    "status": "applied",
                    "consumed_gas": "1000",
                    "consumed_milligas": "1000000"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "transaction",
            "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
            "fee": "0",
            "counter": "780744",
            "gas_limit": "800000",
            "storage_limit": "60000",
            "amount": "27818571",
            "destination": "tz1crghTXjGHpecfMsoMcvV8FA3JqUkBnDEn",
            "metadata": {
                "balance_updates": [

                ],
                "operation_result": {
                    "status": "applied",
                    "balance_updates": [
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                            "change": "-27818571"
                        },
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1crghTXjGHpecfMsoMcvV8FA3JqUkBnDEn",
                            "change": "27818571"
                        },
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                            "change": "-64250"
                        }
                    ],
                    "consumed_gas": "1427",
                    "consumed_milligas": "1427000",
                    "allocated_destination_contract": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I use that response and the forge result to calculate [gas, storage](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html#protocol) [and baker fee](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/004_Pt24m4xi.html#gas-and-fees). For storage I parse the simulation response and check for `paid_storage_size_diff` field to add to the "consumed storage".

I run the `/preapply` sending this:

```
[
    {
        "protocol": "PsDELPH1Kxsxt8f9eWbxQeRxkjfbxoqM52jvs5Y5fBxWWh4ifpo",
        "contents": [
            {
                "storage_limit": "0",
                "gas_limit": "1100",
                "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                "counter": "780743",
                "kind": "delegation",
                "fee": "2555"
            },
            {
                "amount": "27818571",
                "storage_limit": "0",
                "gas_limit": "1527",
                "kind": "transaction",
                "fee": "2625",
                "destination": "tz1crghTXjGHpecfMsoMcvV8FA3JqUkBnDEn",
                "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                "counter": "780744"
            }
        ],
        "signature": "edsig...Pbeo",
        "branch": "BM4p7UaW59i1ScvHnTBc3BUZ31MxeKtp3jsEpjiKjDE5wsS74WL"
    }
]
```

And get a `proto.007-PsDELPH1.storage_exhausted.operation` error as `operation_result` of the transaction.

```
[
    {
        "contents": [
            {
                "kind": "delegation",
                "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                "fee": "2555",
                "counter": "780743",
                "gas_limit": "1100",
                "storage_limit": "0",
                "metadata": {
                    "balance_updates": [
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                            "change": "-2555"
                        },
                        {
                            "kind": "freezer",
                            "category": "fees",
                            "delegate": "tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU",
                            "cycle": 92,
                            "change": "2555"
                        }
                    ],
                    "operation_result": {
                        "status": "backtracked",
                        "consumed_gas": "1000",
                        "consumed_milligas": "1000000"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "kind": "transaction",
                "source": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                "fee": "2625",
                "counter": "780744",
                "gas_limit": "1527",
                "storage_limit": "0",
                "amount": "27818571",
                "destination": "tz1crghTXjGHpecfMsoMcvV8FA3JqUkBnDEn",
                "metadata": {
                    "balance_updates": [
                        {
                            "kind": "contract",
                            "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                            "change": "-2625"
                        },
                        {
                            "kind": "freezer",
                            "category": "fees",
                            "delegate": "tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU",
                            "cycle": 92,
                            "change": "2625"
                        }
                    ],
                    "operation_result": {
                        "status": "backtracked",
                        "errors": [
                            {
                                "kind": "temporary",
                                "id": "proto.007-PsDELPH1.storage_exhausted.operation"
                            }
                        ],
                        "balance_updates": [
                            {
                                "kind": "contract",
                                "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                                "change": "-27818571"
                            },
                            {
                                "kind": "contract",
                                "contract": "tz1crghTXjGHpecfMsoMcvV8FA3JqUkBnDEn",
                                "change": "27818571"
                            },
                            {
                                "kind": "contract",
                                "contract": "tz1Ydpp4ibTrGSPn2i6cqQZ6arWieUbcfWVn",
                                "change": "-64250"
                            }
                        ],
                        "consumed_gas": "1427",
                        "consumed_milligas": "1427000",
                        "allocated_destination_contract": true
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "signature": "edsig...Pbeo"
    }
]
```

What I'm missing on my calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storage_exhausted` means the `storage_limit` you have set is too low for your operation.

You have set 0. Your dry-run came back with `"allocated_destination_contract": true`. You need to pay an allocation fee to cover the cost of assigning the new address. Set your storage limit to 257